# Evaluate locally ToDictionary after GroupBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following Entity Framework Core query:

```
var result = await products
  .Select(x => new { 
    PackageId = x.PackageId, 
    Price = x.Price 
  })
  .GroupBy(x => x.PackageId)
  .Select(x => new { 
    PackageId = x.Key,
    TotalPrice = x.Sum(y => y.Price) 
  })
  .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.PackageId, x => new Model { 
    TotalPrice = x.TotalPrice 
  });
```

I was able to make this query evaluate on the server.

Is there a way to simplify it and still make sure it evaluates on the server?

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate locally"?

Comment: You can achieve by using only `GroupBy` and `ToDictionaryAsync`

Comment: @DavidG: As the OP mentions Entity Framework, I'd assume they mean "not on the database".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes, but which part, and more importantly, *why*?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper and what does *that* mean? There doesn't seem to be anything in this query that would require local evaluation. There are redundant calls to `Select()` though. Even those should only result in ugly SQL, not an error

Comment: Sorry all. I meant to still make sure to evaluate on the server!

Comment: For starters, save for the final call to `ToDictionaryAsync`, why not use integrated query syntax here (`from p in products group p by p.PackageId into g...`)? This isn't the kind of query that benefits from writing it as a sequence of extension method calls. (Of course, what's "simpler" is quite subjective.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var result = await products
  .GroupBy(x => x.PackageId)
  .Select(x => new { 
    PackageId = x.Key,
    TotalPrice = x.Sum(y => y.Price)
  })
  .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.PackageId, x => new Model { 
    TotalPrice = x.TotalPrice 
  });
```

EF will take care about not to load unnecessary data.